# Webpack not working in my node.js project. fsevents

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, fsevents

I'm currently trying to implement this tutorial:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html

I'm supposed to install `react` and `react-dom` and also `webpack` + `typescript` + `awesome-typescript-loader` + `source-map-loader`, and that's what I did. I also installed `webpack-cli` accordingly to instructions that I got from the command line.

I installed all of them locally (the `react` and `react-dom` as PROD and the rest as DEV dependencies).Currently I don't have any packages installed globally.

After this, that's my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "reactandwebpack-tutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.3",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "webpack": "^4.16.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.4.7",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.6",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2"
  }
}
```

At this point, when I run `npm ls` I get a bunch of errors, because of some optional dependency of webpack that apparently is missing (all the errors in the tree are inside `webpack` and below `fsevents` as following):

```
webpack@4.16.4
(...)watchpack@1.6.0
     (...)chokidar@2.0.4
          (...)fsevents@1.2.4 -> UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY
               And everything below fsevents is also marked with UNMET DEPENDENCY
```

And when I run `webpack` command, I get a "webpack not recognized error".

Anyone can help? I've been trying to wrap my head around this for a while.

PS:

```
Npm -v 5.6.0
Node -v 8.11.3 //(that's what I get from the terminal, 
               //VSCode "About" tells me something different, I don't know why).

Using Visual Code

Version 1.24.0
Date 2018-06-06T17:35:40.560Z
Shell 1.7.12
Renderer 58.0.3029.110
Node 7.9.0
Architecture x64
```

Comment: I kept researching this subject. I don't think that the `fsevents UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY` error and the fact that webpack is not being recognized are related. `fsevents`is for MAC OS and I'm using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because it was not linked to your env. When you install something globally, you have access to it everywhere, hence it works just by doing `webpack`. Since you installed everything locally, the binaries are located inside `node_modules/.bin`.

You have two options when you install something locallly.

1. Use npm scripts (npm run build, watch... whatever).
2. `./node_modules/.bin/moduleName --flags`

It is easier to create a npm script and add all the commands there.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

Not sure the reason but it had something to do with the ./bin folder with the webpack-cli "ambient variable" not being available (I don't know it that would be the most accurate description).

When I try to run `webpack`, I get "not recognized error".

But when I run `nodemodules\.bin\webpack-cli` it works normally.

Everything is installed locally.

I can also run it with options, like `nodemodules\.bin\webpack-cli --help`

Answer (score 0):

If you run "webpack", The CLI will find global webpack with is installed by (npm install webpack -g). To use webpack from local project. you should it to npm script.

package.json

```
{
    "script": {
        "start": "webpack"
    }
}
```

By doing this, you can run **npm start** to run webpack.